# SharePoint 2010 with AD

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2010

We are students and we have to make a project by using SharePoint.

We have already learned the basic steps of SharePoint 2010 but now we have some problems with using the Active Directory. We've deleted SharePoint from the server and afterwards we've installed the AD-role and finished dcpromo. When we’ve reinstalled SharePoint 2010, we have some problems in the configuration of SharePoint. It automatically ask for a Databaseserver but we don't have one in the company of our project.

My question is if there is any possibility to use SharePoint with AD and without a Databaseserver. If it is possible it would be nice to tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally agree with Mark's post, but the one place where it is unsupported to use the "Standalone Server" install is when you are installing to a Domain Controller.  As Tim found out, the SharePoint Installer will not even give you the option if you are targeting a DC.

Tim-  You'll need to install a SQL Server... just download and install the free SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (64-bit edition) from here: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/default.aspx

I would also recommend picking up a copy of "Real World SharePoint 2010: Indispensable Experiences from 22 MVPs" from your library/Amazon/local bookstore.  The very first chapter (by Shane Young) walks through how to create a single server (including AD) demo/test setup that covers all the weird things you need to do to make it work (particularly valuable for the exact problem you cover as well as the pain that is the User Profile Service)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a database server, then you need to choose the SharePoint installation option for 'Standalone Server'.  This will be more than acceptable to complete your project, and will install a SQLserver express edition on the SharePoint server you are using.  Good luck!

Comment: First and foremost, I agree with Mark's answer.  In this very specific case, I would recommend the "Standalone Server" install.  In almost every other case, please avoid using the standalone server install, EVEN IF you plan on having your entire SharePoint server on one server.  In fact, I believe a small class project to be the only acceptable situation to choose "Standalone Server."

Comment: Well when we worked without AD we could choose this option in the SharePoint setup. But when we install the AD-role and install SharePoint afterwards it's like we cannot choose between Standalone or Server Farm. I'll retry it tomorrow and keep you posted.